# startup hangs at message x86: Booting SMP configuration

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, kernel, 17.04

Ubuntu 17.04 hangs at start up when running on battery power. Trying to boot with recovery, it is possible to see that it always hangs with the following message
x86: Booting SMP configuration
similar to
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2359386

It appears to not progress in any reasonable time and does not respond to any keyboard input.

Pluging the laptop to a power supply and rebooting (after forced shutdown), it boots without any problem.

Running Ubuntu 17.04 on a Lenovo P50, kernel 4.10.0-20-generic

Booting to 16.04 works fine every time.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Best regards

Comment: In the link below follows a link to photo of the laptop screen at hangup
(https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8xnhQPO10b4bVFHeGFMWlRjbE0)

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved by updating the BIOS, as discussed in:
https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/632650

Comment: And how to do that in a virtual machine?

Comment: I do not have much experience with virtual machines. If the problem and machine are the same, my guess would be to update the BIOS on the machine and only then run the virtual machine.